# How to turn on Visual Studio 2008 .css Intellisense on .less file

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008, intellisense, less

Does anyone know how to enable *Css intellisense* in a non .css file extension? 
I have a .less file that is basically a .css file, but **Visual Studio 2008** will not use *Css intellisense* on the file.
I have seen alot of plugin doing this for VS2010 et 2012, but none for 2008.
Anyone have an idea?
Thank you

Comment: I think there just for Visual Studio 2010-2012: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CoffeeScriptSassAndLESSSupportForVisualStudioAndASPNETWithTheMindscapeWebWorkbench.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Two years ago we (our dev. team) can't even turn on proper syntax highlighting (this makes me crazy). But you can easily edit .less in Sublime Text 2 or in Adobe Dreamweaver as I do, after hours of investigations.

See https://github.com/danro/LESS-sublime